# Octave distribution plots not working

Tags: plot, octave, distribution

I am trying to plot the cdf of a uniform distribution in octave but I am not getting the cdf. I am simply getting the original distribution. Also the original distribution, which is meant to be a uniform distribution, is not a uniform distribution at all!

Here is my octave code:

```
x = unifrnd(0,1,100,1);
hist(x)
cdfPlot = unifcdf(x)
hist(cdfPlot)
```

The histogram for the 1st one (`hist(x)`):

[image]

and the second one (`hist(cdfPlot)`) :
[image]

I also tried to use `cdfplot(x)` in octave but it said :

> warning: the 'cdfplot' function belongs to the statistics package from
>   Octave Forge but has not yet been implemented.
>
> Please read http://www.octave.org/missing.html to learn how you can
>   contribute missing functionality.

please help!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the submitted code, what you are trying to do is obtain a sample from a uniform distribution and then show a flat (mostly) histogram corresponding to a uniform distribution and a line corresponding to the cumulative distribution of the distribution.

For the first part:
Of course, with 100 samples (and no averaging), you are not going to observe a flat distribution, but if you try:

```
x=unifrnd(0,1,100000,1);
hist(x);
```

Then you are more likely to get a flat-looking histogram.

For the second part:
`unifcdf(x,A,B)` will return the value of a uniform distribution's CDF at some value x, between the interval set by parameters A,B. That is, the value of the CDF model itself, **NOT** the cumulative sum of the sample's histogram. To obtain that, you need to:

```
x=unifrnd(0,1,100000,1);
[counts, intervals] = hist(x);
xCDF = cumsum(counts);
bar(xCDF);
```

Finally, if you are looking for the model values, that is the values that would be returned by a formula describing a distribution, then for the uniform distribution that would be a probability of `(1/nBins)` between your A, B interval (in this case, 0,1) and a count of `(1/nBins)*NSamples`, while the CDF would be a line of slope `(1/nBins)` (i.e. the interval of the density function) and of `binNum*((1/nBins)*NSamples)`. In the example above and using the default `nBins` for `hist` which is 10, `x` is decomposed to 10 intervals each with an approximate number of counts of 10000 items of `x` and the last value of the cumulative sum is 100000 which is of course the total number of samples in `x`.

For more information please see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29).

Hope this helps.